# How to return custom error code in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a trigger statement like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_customer_address UPDATE OF address ON customers 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE orders SET address = new.address WHERE customer_name = old.name;
    -- RAISE ...
  END;
END;
```

**EDIT:**

I want to do a step:

```
int result = sqlite3_step(statement);
```

I know `result` returns the result code like `SQLITE_DONE`, `SQLITE_ROW`, and `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`. I also discovered that `RAISE ABORT` within `TRIGGER` returns `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT` to `result`.

Is there a way for me to create a custom error code? I want to do something like

```
int result = sqlite3_step(statement);
// get custom error code here
```

Is it possible to raise with a custom error code in sqlite? Or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an error using the RAISE() function.
You have to use pre-defined error codes (IGNORE, ABORT, FAIL or ROLLBACK) **but** you can add a custom message:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_customer_address UPDATE OF address ON customers 
BEGIN
  UPDATE orders SET address = new.address WHERE customer_name = old.name;
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN ( (SELECT * from orders WHERE address = 'old address!!') IS NOT NULL)
    THEN RAISE (FAIL, 'Can still find old address, not everything was updated!')
  END;
END;
```

Note that RAISE() is meant to be used only when something was wrong, see [the doc](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#raise-function) for more information about raise() behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse you can define custom error codes or messages. All messages sent by

> raise(ERR, "message")

can be retreived in C/C++ [through](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)

```
const char *sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3*);
```